# Include an external library in cmake from flags

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link an external library, let's call it `foo`, which is not compiled with cmake.
`foo` is installed and I can access its cxx flags and link flags via

```
foo-config --cflags
foo-config --libs
```

I can easily use the above in a Makefile, but I want to switch to cmake.
What would be the correct approach to create an imported library called `foo` in my CMakeLists.txt?

I would like to use a modern cmake approach if possible (using targets instead of global cmake variables).

I tried the following:

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND foo-config --cflags
  RESULT_VARIABLE FOO_EXISTS
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO_FLAGS_RAW
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

execute_process(
  COMMAND foo-config --libs
  RESULT_VARIABLE FOO_EXISTS
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO_LIBS_RAW
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

if (FOO_EXISTS EQUAL "0")
  separate_arguments(FOO_FLAGS UNIX_COMMAND "${FOO_FLAGS_RAW}")
  separate_arguments(FOO_LIBS UNIX_COMMAND "${FOO_LIBS_RAW}")
endif()

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(
    FOO_FLAGS_RAW
    FOO_LIBS_RAW
    )

add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)

target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC ${FOO_FLAGS})
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS ${FOO_LIBS}
    )
```

but when I link the library to my target it seems that the compilation flags are not passed (they do not show up when I use VERBOSE=1).
Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*without success*" doesn't tell us much. What went wrong? What worked and what didn't? Please be *specific* about **what** went wrong. Include relevant **error message** in your post, and/or any unexpected behavior.

Comment: In CMake libraries are linked via `target_link_libraries` command. Setting LINK_FLAGS property is wrong for this purpose.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand, but I m given just something which looks like ` -Wl,-rpath,/opt/python/3.7.2/lib -L/home/amlucas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/foo -lfoo -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/amlucas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/foo -L/home/amlucas/foo/build/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/amlucas/foo/build/lib  -L/home/amlucas/foo/build/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/opt/python/3.7.2/lib -lpython3.7m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic`

Comment: You need to parse this output and extract `-l` options. See how FindPkgConfig module does that for `pkg-config` output: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes that is what I feared :) ok thank you very much, I ll do that

Comment: @amlucas If you get a working solution, please post an answer to your question showing your solution so others can learn from it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, I did not want to write the whole find module myself.
I just created a pkg-config file and used the cmake module already written for that purpose.
Thanks @Tsyvarev for the suggestion!